# Distance between consecutive occurrences of a character

Tags: python, find-occurrences

I need to write a program that will determine the length of the spaces between successive occurrences of a given character. If the occurrences are adjacent, the space between them is considered to be 1.

I can only calculate between two signs

```
text = input ('enter text')
find = input ('enter a search character')
x = text.find(find)

y = text.rfind(find)
   
dist = text.rfind(find) - text.find(find)
print(dist)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Example output would be good.

Comment: str.find() takes a start index argument also. You can make use of that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Comment: The example result gives the distance between the first two characters, but what about the next characters?

Comment: It actually gives the distance between the first and last instances of the search character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will **output the distances into a list**.

```
text = "Maybe it's in the gutter, where I left my lover. What an expensive fate."
find = input('Enter a search character')

spaces_list = [len(x) + 1 for x in text.split(find)[1:-1]]
print(spaces_list)
```

### Output

```
>>> Enter a search character
>>> t

>>> [7, 6, 1, 16, 15, 17]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I meant